# Cannot create rounded top left in triangle object with border-top-left-radius and border-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I add border radius when using border-width? I want to add **border-top-left-radius** of **15px**.

I have this code to create a triangle object and it looks nice, but I want the object have border radius at top left. However, if I use `border-top-left-radius: 15px;` the object is not triangle but a square.

Currently I use Bootstrap 3.3.7.

```css
.exclusive-price{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 160px 160px 0 0;
    border-color: #C00000 transparent transparent transparent;
    /* if use this the object will be a square */
    /*
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    */

}
.exclusive-price>label{
    position: relative;
    top: -110px;
    left: -5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    min-width: 140px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="exclusive-price"><label>Most Effective</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a container and make some changes on CSS to achieve this:

```css
.corner-label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.exclusive-price {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 160px 160px 0 0;
  border-color: #C00000 transparent transparent transparent;
  /* if use this the object will be a square */
  /*
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  */
}
.exclusive-price>label{
  position: relative;
  top: -110px;
  left: -5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: normal;
  min-width: 140px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="corner-label">
  <div class="exclusive-price"><label>Most Effective</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is useful for me and can implemented in pricing table.

Answer (score 0):

According to the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) CSS has something called as box model.  CSS box model describes the rectangular boxes that are generated for elements in the DOM. That is why if you apply border radius to top left corner the object appears as a rectangle/square.

```css
.triangle{
    border-color: #C00000 white white #C00000;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 160px 160px 0px 0px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
.exclusive-price>label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: -5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    min-width: 140px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<div class="triangle">  </div>
<div class="exclusive-price"><label>Most Effective</label></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there is a white part in bottom right, so I think this is like two triangle, I can't change it to transparent btw. :)

Comment: Visually that appears as two triangles. But, its a square divided with two colors white and #C00000 as CSS follows box model. As I have spent some time solving the issue, would you please upvote?